# How to access the params in controller ember.js

Tags: ember.js

This is my router.js code.

```
this.route('contact',{'path': '/contact/:chat_id'});
```

and This is my route.js code.

```
model(params) {

  return this.store.findRecord("chat", params.chat_id)
},
```

and This is my controller.js code and can i use like this. It shows error as null value
please help me. How to use params in controller

```
recordChat: function() {

  var chat = this.get(params.chat_id)

  Ember.RSVP.hash({
    offer_id: chat,
  })
}
```

Comment: What error? You should consider updating your post so as to provide the needed information.

Comment: It shows null value

Comment: You don't return anything from your `recordChat` function. Also when do you call that function?

Comment: `params` is argument is passed `model()`, but that will not be accessible in `recordChat` method. and also instead of `chat_id` try `chatId`. and try introducing `queryParams:['chatId']` in controller

Comment: Bro can u please tell me in details about queryParams :[ ' chatId ' ]

Comment: Ignore my comments, that one is for queryParams and not for dynamic segments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your route.js, you need to call the setupController function like this:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
    this._super(...arguments);
    controller.set('chat', model);
}
```

Now you have access to it in your controller by calling:

```
recordChat() {
   const chat = this.get('chat');
   //  if you don't call the setupController function, you could also do:
   // const chat = this.get('model') or this.get('model.id') if you want the id only
}
```

**UPDATE:**

See working [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/7740ad1976ecd3a642e8835f2a7e3862?numColumns=2&openFiles=controllers.contact.js%2Croutes.contact.js) here

Comment: `this.get('chat')` or `this.get('model')` don't return anything? That cannot be ;). How do you check if it's working? Your recordChat doesn't do anything at the moment...

Comment: Yes Bro it doesn't work. This recordChat will work when user fill the data in input box and click on save button and in chat_id params will have to fill in offerid place

Comment: is there another options to take the query params in controller

Comment: I created a working twiddle for you. See updated answer

Comment: Really Thanks Bro I will follow you and i will let you know it is work or not

Comment: Thanks Bro Now Working Successfully.

Answer (score 8):

**Edited for 2021**: There's actually probably a much simpler way to do this now in Ember. See https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.27.0/routing/query-params/

**Original Answer**

I think the simplest answer is to create a variable in route and then set it in the setupController:

**your_route.js**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    this.set('myParam',params.my_Params);
    
    // Do Model Stuff...
  },
  setupController(controller, model) {
    // Call _super for default behavior
    this._super(controller, model);
    // Implement your custom setup after
    controller.set('myParam', this.get('myParam'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Here `controllerFor` is not necessary, you can just say `controller.set(`

Comment: Thanks! Did not know that. I will change it!

Comment: I must admit don't like the model() hook setting stuff like that as it's purpose is only to return the model

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fetch the id you want from the model because you used the parameter chat_id to find the record and that id is now part of your chat object (which is the route model itself).

So, in your controller you just need to do: this.get('model').id